# yii2 :how to change language of rbac

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-extension

i used yii2 users and rbac  ( dekturim ) in my project

i did change language of project to fa-IR and changed true

but in rbac language not changed !

this is my config in console.php

```
 'modules' => [
    'rbac' => 'dektrium\rbac\RbacWebModule',
],
```

and this is my config in web.php

```
$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'sourceLanguage' => 'fa-IR',
'language' => 'fa-IR',
```

Comment: in users tab my language changed to fa-IR  but in permission tab language is en ! why?

Comment: What is 'sourceLanguage' config? Must be  'en-US'